# if $s_n<t_n$, can we say $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

While I was studying properties of limit and sequences, I found a theorm that says 'if {$s_n$}, {$t_n$} are convergent sequences, then $s_n \le t_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$ implies that $$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n \le \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n$$
this proof is quite easy to construct, as you can say

> Given $\epsilon>0$ choose $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $|s_n-S| < \epsilon/2$ and $|t_n-T| < \epsilon/2$ then $S-T = (S-s_n) + (t_n-T) + s_n - t_n$ and use triangle inequality to finish

but I heard that following is NOT TRUE, and I don't know why?

**if $s_n<t_n$, can we say $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} s_n < \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} t_n$?**

Comment: Consider $s_n=0 < t_n=1/n$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's not true. Let $s_n = 1 $ and $t_n = 1 + 1/n$, for all $n\in \Bbb N$. Then $s_n < t_n$ for every $n$, but $\lim_{n\to \infty} s_n = 1 = \lim_{n\to \infty} t_n$.

Answer (score 1):

**It is not true**. However, if $a_n < b_n$ (or $a_n \leq s_n$ as seen in your theorem) for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and their limits exist, then you **can** instead say that
$$\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n \leq \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n. $$

For example, if $a_n = 1-\frac{1}{n}$ and $b_n = 1$, then $a_n < 1$ for all $n$ but $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n\to \infty} b_n = 1.$